# Cannot get the URL segment from the model page only

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, model

i cant access url segment in model page in  my query

```
function get_event_list() {
$id =$this->uri->segment(3);

$this->db->select('CONVERT_TZ( SUBSTRING(`s_start`, 1, 16), diff, @@session.time_zone) AS date1');

$this->db->from('sessions');

$this->db->where("s_tutor", $id );
```

when i set $id manually it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this on.
Assuming you have a URL of http://yourdomain.com/get_event_list/12

Controller

```
    function get_event_list() {
       $id =$this->uri->segment(3);
       if($id){
           $this->your_model->get_event_list($id);
       }else{
           show_404();
       }
    }
```

Model

```
    function get_event_list($id) 
        $this->db->select('CONVERT_TZ( SUBSTRING(`s_start`, 1, 16), diff,  
        @@session.time_zone) AS date1');
        $this->db->from('sessions');
        $this->db->where("s_tutor", $id);
    }
```

Comment: still have the problem cannot ger url segment from model the code is fine if i do it manually like  function get_event_list($id=3) {

Comment: This one is from the controller, not the model. If you want to use the URI segment, you need to get segment URL in the controller and past it to the model. Don't call the URI segment in the model.

Comment: how can i do it . i must call segment from model because i'm using it in sql query

Comment: Check my answer above again, I edited it. Try it that way.

Comment: sorry , the same problem